# How to summarize in PL/SQL

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, aggregate

Given that I have a table contains user data, like this:

```
userID     calltime     result 
1         10:20         1
1         11:00         2
1         11:30         1
2         9:30          1
2         11:00         1
3         10:00         1
3         10:30         2
3         11:00         1
3         11:30         2
```

Now I want to summarize it like that:

```
userID     result1    result2
1             2         1
2             2         0
3             2         2
(total)       6         3
```

for me, summarizing user data is fine, but how can I add total row in a query? UNION does not work with this.

Thank you so much for this.

EDIT: this my current query, of course, it does not work:

```
  PROCEDURE P_SUMMARIZE_CALL
  (
    pStartDate IN DATE,
    pEndDate IN DATE,
    SummaryCur  OUT MEGAGREEN_CUR    
  )
  IS
  BEGIN
    OPEN SUMMARYCUR FOR
    SELECT USERID, TOTALCALLS,CONNECTEDCALLS,RATE,NOANSWER FROM
    (((SELECT USERID,
            count(CALLID) AS TOTALCALLS, 
            sum(CONNECTED) as CONNECTEDCALLS, 
            sum(CONNECTED)/count(CALLID)*100 || '%' AS RATE,
            (count(CALLID) - sum(CONNECTED)) AS NOANSWER 
    FROM CALLLOGS
    WHERE STARTTIME BETWEEN pStartDate AND pEndDate  
   group by USERID) c
   FULL OUTER JOIN USERS u
   ON c.USERID = u.ID)

    UNION ALL 
     (SELECT NULL,count(CALLID) AS TOTALCALLS, 
            sum(CONNECTED) as CONNECTEDCALLS, 
            sum(CONNECTED)/count(CALLID)*100 || '%' AS RATE,
            (count(CALLID) - sum(CONNECTED)) AS NOANSWER 
    FROM CALLLOGS
    WHERE STARTTIME BETWEEN pStartDate AND pEndDate group by NULL));   

  END;
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're using a `FULL OUTER JOIN`? This is probably doing more work than necessary since it looks you actually want a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` unless I'm mistaken. And it will bring back a whole lot of completely null rows since you are using c.USERID instead of u.ID

Comment: that what I wanted. When displayed in gridcontrol, null value will be converted to 0, if i don't use RIGHT OUTER JOIN, user who does not have call will be ignored

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are using GROUP BY to generate your current result. (PS: Please post your current query as it is rather hard to guess what you are doing to get that result).

To get what you want use GROUP BY ROLLUP instead of GROUP BY.

> UNION does not work with this.

Yes, actually that will work too. But I'd suggest UNION ALL rather than UNION as your result set seems to already to contain only distinct rows so there is no point using extra calculation time searching for duplicate rows to remove.

Comment: @Vimvq1987: Change `group by USERID` to `group by rollup(USERID)`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bit faster way of doing this...

Assuming you can only get a value of 1 or 2 on the field "result", this would work:

```
SELECT  userid
,       SUM(DECODE (result, 1, 1, 0)) as result1
,       SUM(DECODE (result, 2, 1, 0)) as result2
FROM    x
GROUP BY userid;
```

This would generate the expected output:

```
USERID    RESULT1   RESULT2                
--------- --------- ---------
1         2         1
2         2         0 
3         2         2
```

If the possible values on the field result are more than 1 or 2, you could add more sum-decode rows, or do the aforementioned PL/SQL procedure.

Comment: Altough DECODE is more compact, using CASE is more flexible and also more standard SQL.